# can I change timezone saved in Firestore timestamp field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timezone

so from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/struct/firebase/firestore/timestamp) it said that

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
> calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
> nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time

but here is my timestamp field in my document

[image]

as you can see, there is UTC+7. I am from Indonesia, and my Firestore database is also in region asia-southeast2 (Jakarta,Indonesia).

my question is .....

can I actually change that timezone ? even though the documentation says that timestamp is independent from any timezone. but I don't Understand why Firestore can get that UTC+7, which is correct because I send the data from Indonesia (UTC+7)

I try to manipulate date object in my Android app, and send data using different timezone (UTC+9), but it will always be saved as UTC+7.

so basically I am trying to find out if there is a bug in my code or timezone in firestore can't be changed

Comment: Assuming the screenshot you share is from the Firestore console, that is just how the console **displays** the timestamp. The value is (as the documentation says) **stored** as an offset to the epoch in UTC.

I don't think there's a way to change the timezone that the Firebase console. If you want to know if there's a big in your code, it'd help to see the minimal code that you are asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Firestore, timezones are not encoded into timestamp values.  All timestamps are measured in UTC.  This is normal for dates and times for all major operating system.  What you see in the console is the timestamp value formatted for the timezone that your **local** computer is currently configured for.  If you want to see a different timezone there, you would have to change your computer's configured timezone.  Change the timestamp value itself won't really help.

Your code should only create and manipulate timestamp values that are also measured in UTC.  If you are somehow receive data formatted form another timezone, you should convert it to UTC first before creating a timestamp.

Comment: I wonder if this is still true. I'm seeing timestamps in one document containing different timzones.. specifically UTC then UTC +1 is this intentional?

Comment: I am currently pushing Dart DateTime parameters in Firestore documents in UTC, and when I query for that document in is returned in the local time (though it is adjusted correctly, so they are the same moment in time).

Comment: @jcodes How are you observing that they are "returned" in local time? How do you know that they aren't just being *printed* in local time, because that might be the default for whatever you're using to print them?  It's normally the responsibility of the code that turns a timestamp into a string to make that decision.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was debugging my code and at various breakpoints checking the various DateTime vars' isUtc value and/or utcOffset parameter values. To make clear, I convoluted my issue with the OP's question, this is not a Firebase thing it is a Flutter/Dart thing. Sorry for my confusion