# Get timeStamp from firebase without changing its timeZone

Tags: typescript, firebase, time, google-cloud-functions, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timeStamp field in firebase saved in UTC+3 as local time. But when I got it in firebase cloud functions it returns in UTC. How can I not allow firebase to change the timezone when I get this field?
I mean if the time is 10 am UTC+3 I don't want to get it 7 am UTC. I need it to stay 10 am.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way for doing what you want.

All timestamps in Firestore are saved in UTC. The timezone of the user who saved the timestamp is not saved with the timestamp value. More details in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241230/can-i-change-timezone-saved-in-firestore-timestamp-field) (and comment)

You could add an extra field in the Firestore document with the timezone and do the calculation in your Cloud Function (with a library like `moment.js` or any [alternative](https://medium.com/swlh/best-moment-js-alternatives-5dfa6861a1eb)) to generate a value according to this time zone.

Comment: // The date saved in firebase field is 10 UTC+3 but am receiving itt as 7 UTC 
            and I don't want this
            const classTime = element2.data().scheduleSlotDate;   
            console.log("date get1", classTime);
            // OR
            console.log("date get", classTime.toDate());
            //2021-05-25T07:00:00.000Z  {UTC too}

@Renaud Tarnec, so this is normal?

Comment: When you say "I am receiving it" it all depends **where** you read it (receive it). If it is in the Firebase console (the front-end), the value is displayed according to the time zone from your computer/browser. If you read in the CF it is in UTC (there is no timezone set for the back-end)